# Comparing variables in while statement python syntax error

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

Hi I'm quite new to Python but have programmed previously in other C based languages. I keep running into a syntax error but I can't figure out what it means.

```
x = 1
Primary = 0
Secondary = 0

while x != 0:
    Primary + 1
    while Secondary <= Primary
        Ed.PlayBeep()
        Secondary + 1
    Secondary = 0
```

Comment: You are missing a `:` after condition in if statement.

Comment: I'm curious, is `Primary + 1` equivalent to `Primary += 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `:`:

```
while Secondary <= Primary:
   ...
```

Also, did you mean `Primary += 1` and `Secondary += 1`? You're incrementing those values but not assigning them.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing colons in second while, it should go:

```
    while Secondary <= Primary:
```